# var card= cleanNum: function(){....} what does this cleanNum: mean?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I want to know what cleanNum means in the following code. Is it the function name or does it represent something else?

```
//code snippet 1
var creditCard = {
  cleanNum : function(number){
    return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
  }
};
```

Q1. I do not get the meaning of cleanNum. Can you please explain what is the significance of cleanNum().

Q2. If I am using it in another function called another_func(), how do I call the code snippet 1?

Is the below code snippet same as above?

```
//code snippet 2
function cleanNum(number){
  //sample code
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the snippet 1 ..

Comment: Do you mean this ?,  `var creditCard = {
  cleanNum : function(number){
    return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
  }
}`

Comment: yes. you are right. I will edit it

Comment: this will help you to understand javascript namespacing https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing´s first: `var x = {}` defines a new object, every variable declared within the {} becomes a field of that object.

The following would create an object (referenced by the variable `creditCard`) with a field number

```
var creditCard = {
  number: '3432-2342-34243'
};
```

So as to Q1, the significance of cleanNum, is that it's a member of of the object `creditCard`. Only instead of containing an int/string/date etc, it contains a `function`

```
var creditCard = {
  cleanNum : function(number){
    return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
  }
};
```

As to Q2, the function itself would the same, only the scope is not. When defined directly, it's accessible directly, if defined inside the object, it's only accessible through that object:

```
creditCard.cleanNum(somenumber);
```

To go a step further, to demonstrate that the function itself is just a function, you could define the function outside of creditCard and reuse the function inside your object:

```
function cleanNumGlobal(number){
    return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
  }

var creditCard = {    
  cleanNum : cleanNumGlobal
};

//both call the same function:
console.log(cleanNumGlobal('2432-2423-234'));
console.log(creditCard.cleanNum('2432-2423-234'));
```

As a side note: normally the function such as this, would use properties of the object itself, so instead of using a parameter number, it would use a property `number` of the object itself (or clean the number upon setting that property). But that is besides the question scope ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the code actually does not compile with this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I think what you intended was

```
var cleanNum = function(number){
     return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
}
```

This is similar to the other way, which is known as function declaration. The difference lies in when the code is loaded. When declaring a function like function cleanNum() {...}, that code is loaded before any code execution, whereas the expression (seen in code block above) is loaded during execution. If you try to call it before it's loaded, it will fire an error.

**EDIT**

Just saw the edit made to your code block. When you do:

```
var creditCard = 
    { 
        cleanNum : function(number){ return number.replace(/[- ]/g,"");
        }    
    }
```

you are storing cleanNum under the creditCard object, and to call it you would have to use

```
creditCard.cleanNum(param)
```

This is not the same as the original, since before you could access it directly by

```
cleanNum(param)
```

Comment: I am sorry. I saw the code on a Screen Cast. 
I edited it as @KishoreSahas pointed out in the comments to question.

Answer (score 1):

I want to know what cleanNum means in the following code. Is it the function name or does it represent something else?

> it is just a function name

Q1. I do not get the meaning of cleanNum. Can you please explain what is the significance of cleanNum().

> `cleanNum()` just a `function` name which is under the [namespace](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) `creditCard`.

Q2. If I am using it in another function called another_func(), how do I call the code snippet 1?

> you can call the function by `creditCard.cleanNum(numbr)`

Is the below code snippet same as above?

> No it is not

To understand more on *namespacing in javascript* : [click here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. I do not get the meaning of cleanNum. Can you please explain what is the significance of cleanNum().

`cleanNum` is the function name that is define with anonymous function in object element. That function will make the `number` clean by removing dashes  ("-") in it. I guess that will be the credit card numbers, so it'll input something similar to `1-2345-6789-01-2` and then return with only number (no dashes) , in this case will be `123456789012`.

> Q2. If I am using it in another function called another_func(), how do I call the code snippet 1?

You can call it with

```
creditCard.cleanNum(number);
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can define the cleanNum function in two ways:

1)`function cleanNum(number) { }`

This way, cleanNum is loaded into the memory before code execution starts. You may not need this.

2)`cleanNum=function(number) { }`

This way, cleanNum is loaded into the memory every time it is called.

Also you can access cleanNum function using:

```
creditCard.cleanNum(number)
```